# add newlines in a substitution with array contents in perl

Tags: perl

I have a code with some substitutes like this :

```
  foreach (@mail_template) {
     s/%appname%/$appl/g;
     s/%envir%/$env/g;
     s/%status%/$final_status/g;
     s/%date%/$date/g;
     s/%from%/$from/g;
     s/%to%/$to/g;
     s/%filename%/$main::log/g;
     s/%checklist%/@checklist_items/g;
     s/%logs%/@error_logs/g;
     print TMP "$_";
  }
```

however, it looks like the substitution with an array like :

```
s/%checklist%/@checklist_items/g;
```

is pasting all the contents of the array without any newlines

in the final file, I have something like :

```
array_entry1 array_entry2 array_entry3 array_entry N
```

all on the same line (which is normal).

my question is : how do I get the same behavior but with newlines added after each entry ?

I would like the substitution to give something like this instead :

```
array_entry1
array_entry2
array_entry3
array_entryN
```

I suppose I could add a '\n' to each array entry or something ?

thanks
regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the value to a scalar variable and use it instead:

```
my $checklist = join "\n", @checklist_items;
s/%checklist%/$checklist/g;
```

[join](http://p3rl.org/join) doesn't add a newline to the last item, so you need to add it manually if needed.

Note that using a substitution table might be easier to maintain:

```
my %replace = ( appname   => $appl,
                envir     => $env,
                status    => $final_status,
                checklist => join("\n", @checklist_items),
                ... );

s/%(\w+)%/$replace{$1}/g for @mail_template;
```

Using [Template](http://p3rl.org/Template) or a similar module might be even easier and more flexible.